# While Running the vba script i am getting error Microsoft VBScript runtime error: object required : 'DoCmd'

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

while running the vb script through command prompt i am getting the error stating that Microsoft VBScript runtime error: object required : 'DoCmd' .

Please help me out as earliest as possible.

```
ExecuteInsert
Sub ExecuteInsert()

Dim sheetPath
Dim dbs, DbFullName, acc
    Set acc = createobject("Access.Application")

    DbFullName = "D:\G\Diamond\FINAL MS-Access\Demo\MS-Access project.accdb"
    Set dbs = acc.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(DbFullName, False, False)

dbs.Execute "Delete from TempRoadMap"

sheetPath = "C:\Users\270784\Desktop\CSPRV scheduled work - 2014 through 1-26-14.xlsx"



DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel97, "TempRoadMap", _
 sheetPath, True

MsgBox "Imported Sheet1 from " & sheetPath & " Successfully!"

dbs.Execute "Delete from RoadMap"
    dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO [RoadMap] ( Release_Name,SPRF,SPRF_CC,Estimate_Type,PV_Work_ID,SPRF_Name,Estimate_Name,Project_Phase,CSPRV_Status,Scheduling_Status,Impact_Type,Onshore_Staffing_Restriction,Applications,Total_Appl_Estimate,Total_CQA_Estimate,Estimate_Total,Requested_Release,Item_Type,Path) SELECT [TempRoadMap.Release Name], [TempRoadMap.SPRF], [TempRoadMap.Estimate (SPRF-CC)],[TempRoadMap.Estimate Type],[TempRoadMap.PV Work ID],[TempRoadMap.SPRF Name],[TempRoadMap.Estimate Name],[TempRoadMap.Project Phase],[TempRoadMap.CSPRV Status],[TempRoadMap.Scheduling Status],[TempRoadMap.Impact Type],[TempRoadMap.Onshore Staffing Restriction],[TempRoadMap.Applications],[TempRoadMap.Total Appl Estimate],[TempRoadMap.Total CQA Estimate],[TempRoadMap.Estimate Total],[TempRoadMap.Requested Release],[TempRoadMap.Item Type],[TempRoadMap.Path] FROM [TempRoadMap] "

 dbs.Close
MsgBox "Done"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For the line

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel97, "TempRoadMap", _
     sheetPath, True
```

Unless you have defined elsewhere `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel97` does not exist, and you should be using `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8`, see [here for the different types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196017%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Not sure if this is correct but I have seen [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce4275bf-5720-4ee4-8aee-0674cfdf673a/objaccessdocmdrunsavedimportexport-from-vbscript) that you should use `object.docmd` so in your case would it be

```
acc.docmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel97, "TempRoadMap", _
         sheetPath, True
```

Comment: Brother , now it is showing TransferSpreadsheet is not available ?:(

Comment: Has this worked before? Because i am reading comments on other forums that this object is only available in VBA, and MSDN sometimes only refers to VBA and not VB, VBS etc "You can use the methods of the DoCmd object to run Microsoft Office Access actions from Visual Basic."[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192694(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: yes brother, its a object for VBA only....but when i am running the script through MS Access it worked fine...But when i am running with command prompt it stating these error...help me to resolve this issue??

Comment: So you are running a VBS in cmd, which fails as the docmd is not supported, isn't this the long and short of it?, or are you trying to pipe VBA code through cmd?

Comment: yes bro i am running VBS through cmd that time it is showing Microsoft VBScript runtime error: object required : 'DoCmd' .

Comment: but as has been said, and you have confirmed the object is not for VBS only VBA, so it would never accept it? Am i going down the wrong route here?

Comment: Actuuly i am need to load one table in MS access through data present in Excel sheet..so i have to write one script which will run through command prompt or batch file ??

Comment: i would look at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184346/push-data-from-excel-to-access-database) I think you need to use the ADODB.Connection in VBscript to achieve what you need. If this answers your question, please accept this answer. Thanks bro :)

Comment: Can i have any suggestion in the script i have given, because in that i am loading the temp table first with the help of excel in Access table and then i am putting data into main table..

Comment: My answer would be to use the link to the question and research the adodb connection, then start a new question if you are having problems after you have tried to build it. I've not done anywork on Excel - Access scripting so wouldn't be the best person to assist. If this is what you are after please accept this to your question. Many Thanks for your quick repsonses